# Как отследить открытие bootstrap спойлера?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть такая разметка:          ))

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="lable">
        <a href="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse">Form controls</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="img.png">
        <p class="lable2">Button</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <img src="img.png">
        <p class="lable2">File chooser</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.block{
  background: #212121;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 270px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #FF4081;
}

.lable{
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "CondPro";
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FF4081;
  color: white;
}
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при открытии **bootstrap collapse** менялся атрибут **height** класса **.block** и атрибут **border-bottom** класса **.lable**

---

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#collapseOne').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
      $(".block").css("height", "ширина");
      $(".lable").css("border-bottom", "рамка");
});
```

Замените `ширина` и `рамка` на нужные Вам значения.

Comment: Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как вызвать метод .collapse('hide') в конструкции `$('#la2c').click(function(){});`